# Github Copilot Auto complete Quotes and Brackets

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, quotes, github-copilot

i have an issue with github copilot's auto complete.
When coding C in vscode, the auto complete suggest me some code but without closing brackets and quotes. how to fix it?

Here is an example of code (just an example, don't care what is it :)), you can see that the suggestion doesn't have the closing quote and bracket.

[image]

I tried to change auto complete settings but nothing changed.